# Is there any purpose for setting the border-radius property to -1?

Tags: css

By chance, while I was scanning through the CSS file found [here](http://static2.wwtdd.com/assets/sk_blog_manager/core-d49bda3ddd08e5bf3359a65db918dfe48102fbbc9fe4756cc567ea905aa1c564.css), I noticed something I have never seen in any CSS resource. The developers who wrote this CSS set the `border-(top-left-|top-right-|bottom-left-|bottom-right-|)radius` properties equal to -1 in several locations within the stylesheet (e.g., search for **border-bottom-left-radius:-1**).

I am aware the `border-radius` properties must follow the format shown [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) (plus additional linked resources within). Now, I can understand 1 typo, but there are over 20 instances of the value `-1` for `border-radius` properties in this stylesheet. So I created a new pen on CodePen and as expected, the value -1 had no effect on the `border-radius` of a relevant element (I used a div of height 100px, width 200px).

When inspecting the element in Firefox (when `border-radius` was set to `-1`), this value was labeled as invalid (same when inspecting the element on Chrome).

Does anyone know if for some browser or scenario `-1` is a valid value for `border-radius`? I am guessing this was simply a purposely-set invalid placeholder used for internal bookkeeping by the developers.

Comment: Based on what is stated as valid on the W3 you need to pass the value on any length unit or % .... so a number without unit is invalid. Also on both situations length or percentage *Negative values are not allowed*

Comment: @DaniP I know this but I am wondering if this is e.g. some browser-specific hack

Comment: I don't think you will find answers here. For all we know, it could be a browser hack. (If there are browsers where -1 will reset the value to the default or something, while it will simple be ignored on most others, this is a trick to cause different results on different browsers.) This is pure speculation though, which is all you're going to get here. Ask the creators of the website in question.

Answer (score 3):

Given that the CSS uses Bootstrap as a starting point, it's highly likely that these negative values are unintentional. The number of rules will be due to the use of a CSS preprocessor (Less or Sass) and the use of variables: Bootstrap leverages variables a great deal, so a simple case of changing one single value - in this case `$border-radius-base` - can result in multiple rules changing.

The final piece of the puzzle: the negative value itself. It looks like the Bootstrap devs subtract 1 from the border radius value in several places; it's likely that it's some kind of adjustment for a 1px border somewhere. My guess is that the at some point someone decided to drop the border radius altogether, set `$border-radius-base` to 0, which in turn led to some negative values popping up. Since the invalid rules get ignored by the browser, no-one notices, apart from the OP!